# Need inputs on Web application development

Tags: python, django, angular, azure, user-interface

I need inputs on tech stack used for building a web application.
Currently I'm using Angular with Django in my application.
But when I'm trying to query SQL databases using Django in my code, if the datasets are with heavy data Django is not completing the query.

How make this work?
Can we use any other technology as backend for Angular to work on large datasets?
Please share your thoughts on this..

I tried with Django but it's giving timeout issues and exiting out of api.
Note: I need to show the result in Angular UI after processing. So I need a better framework that handles heavy processing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the relevant parts of your code.  Please explain what you mean by 'not completing the data'.  Does it randomly stop getting data, or does it get the data up to a certain point?